# How to use Lua table inside redis.call?

Tags: lua, redis

Getting an error in Redis while executing a Lua script in Redis. My confusion is how to use Redis array reply in making second `redis.call`. My use case is bulk deletion of Sorted Set members.

```
127.0.0.1:6380> eval "local list = redis.call('zrevrange','test', 50, -1) return redis.call('zrem', 'test', list)" 0
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_aa5dddbbb039b576aba5f46a99a268339ca2e9d5): @user_script:1: @user_script: 1: Lua redis() command arguments must be strings or integers
```

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Lua's [`unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack) - i.e.:

```
local list = redis.call('zrevrange','test', 50, -1) return
redis.call('zrem', 'test', unpack(list))
```

However, to perform a bulk delete from a Sorted Set based on a range, simply use [`ZREMRANGEBYRANK`](https://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyrank):

```
ZREMRANGEBYRANK test 0 -50
```

Comment: Thanks for both the suggestions.